# Mutate value in dataframe based on a value is present in different rows

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to set certain values to `NA`.
I want to change `column1` value when `value11` is in `column2` to `NA`, because this `value11` has `NA` in `column4` when it is present in `column3`. So essentially I have value in `column1` mutate based on a value located in different rows.

This is the initital dataframe that I have:

```
column1 column2 column3 column4
NA      value1  value2  NA
1       value2  value3  1
1       value5  value6  2
2       value6  value7  1
NA      value10 value11 NA  
1       value11 value12 1
```

This is what I want to have:

```
column1 column2 column3 column4
NA      value1  value2  NA
NA      value2  value3  1
1       value5  value6  2
2       value6  value7  1
NA      value10 value11 NA  
NA      value11 value12 1
```

What I want is if a value in `column3` (here `value2` and `value11`) has `NA` in `column4`, then the value for `column1` should also change to `NA` if this value is present in `column2` (the values `value2` and `value11` here).

Sorry for so many edits, I find it hard to explain.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Dan

Comment: the question is still unclear.  Shall I edit your input data and then can you tell the expected outcome?

Comment: Hello Dan. I am not sure I follow your question correctly.
Are you looking for a way to modify the values of all rows in certain columns whenever you have value11 in a row? 
Or Whenever value11 appears in any row of a column?

Comment: I want to change value of  `column1` if value in `column2` next to it, is also present above in `column3` and has `NA` in `column4` right next to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by simple logic translation this should also work

```
df %>% 
  mutate(column4 = ifelse(column3 %in% (df %>% 
                                          filter(is.na(column1)) %>%
                                          pull(column2)), NA, column4)) %>%
  mutate(column1 = ifelse(column2 %in% (df %>% 
                                          filter(is.na(column4)) %>%
                                          pull(column3)), NA, column1))
  column1 column2 column3 column4
1      NA  value1  value2      NA
2      NA  value2  value3       1
3       1  value5  value6       2
4       2  value6  value7       1
5      NA value10 value11      NA
6      NA value11 value12       1
```

where `df` is

```
df <- read.table(text = "column1 column2 column3 column4
NA      value1  value2  NA
1       value2  value3  1
1       value5  value6  2
2       value6  value7  1
NA      value10 value11 NA  
1       value11 value12 1", header = T)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, but what is the first part for?

`mutate(column4 = ifelse(column3 %in% (df %>% filter(is.na(column1)) %>% pull(column2)), NA, column4)) %>%`
the code seems to work without it too.

Comment: Yes, for this example first part is redundant.  I thought your requirement is both ways so I included it two way round.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this is best done with a self-join. This is complicated by row 6 -- `value5` doesn't appear in `column3` at all, but you don't want to make it `NA`. I believe this works, you can step through it one line at a time to see what's going on:

```
data %>%
  filter(is.na(column4)) %>%
  select(column3) %>%
  mutate(make_na = 1) %>%
  left_join(data, ., by = c("column2" = "column3")) %>%
  mutate(column1 = ifelse(!is.na(make_na), NA, column1)) %>%
  select(-make_na)
  # Joining, by = "column2"
#   column1 column2 column3 column4
# 1      NA  value1  value2      NA
# 2      NA  value2  value3       1
# 3       1  value5  value6       2
# 4       2  value6  value7       1
# 5      NA value10 value11      NA
# 6      NA value11 value12       1
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `ifelse()` would do it.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(column1 = 1, column2 = c("value10", "value11"), column3 = c("value11", "value12"), column4 = 1 )

df %>% 
mutate(column1 = ifelse(test = column3 == "value11", yes = NA, no = column1),
       column4 = ifelse(test = column3 == "value11", yes = NA, no = column4))

  column1 column2 column3 column4
1      NA value10 value11      NA
2       1 value11 value12       1
```

Comment: I am sorry I did not explain myself properly so I have edited the question with more detail.